# Mongo database extremely slow until I restart

Tags: mongodb

I just inherited an application from another developer, and I've been asked to fix some latency issues that users have been experiencing. The problem is that any page that makes db calls to mongo takes several minutes to load in the browser.

When I restart mongo, however, everything speeds up again, and the application functions normally. I see several cron jobs that run throughout the day, and I believe one of these may be causing mongo to slow down.

Unfortunately, I have no experience with mongo (only mysql), and I really don't have any idea of what I'm looking for in terms of things that could be making mongo run so slowly.

Anyways, I was hoping someone could suggest some potential things that could be causing the latency so I can approach this problem better. I have looked in the mongo logs, and the only thing I see that could be of concern is a message that says:

```
warning: can't find plugin [asc]
```

I know this may point to an indexing problem, but are there any other obvious things I should be investigating?

Comment: it's not "can't find plugin" directly - but it means that there may be a query which is specifying its sort query incorrectly - this error means either an index or sort specification is not using 1 or -1 (but probably "1" by mistake.   What you should do is when it's slow run db.currentOp() command at shell prompt and see what's running.  Also in the same logs are there any queries with very long running times logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/pqPvMq7cSBw it looks like one of your queries declared

```
db.a2.find().sort({a:"asc"})
```

rather than

```
db.a2.find().sort({a:1})
```

In MongoDB you need to declare your sorting with either **1 or -1**, there's no **asc or desc** constants for the sorting. So I would recommend that you check if any of your queries runs incorrectly. You can check what queries are running through the log files (with correct profiling settings) http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/ . You may use mongotop (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongotop/) to see where the most time reading/writing data is spent for your collections, as well.